Dataframe manipulation in R - selecting certain values
I have the following issue that I can't find an answer to:
I have a df that looks like this:
  id x1_t1 x1_t2 x1_t3 y1_t1 y1_t2 y1_t3
1  1     0     0     0   100   110   150
2  2     0     0     1   150   140   180
3  3     0     1     1    90   150   160

x1 and y1 are in their multiple times (different time points). Depending on when the x1 variable changes from 0 to 1, I want the respective y1 values, so that the resulting dataframe would look like this:
  id y1_before y1_after
1  1       110      150
2  2       140      180
3  3        90      150

I have already messed around with dplyr quite a bit, but haven't found a working solution. Perhaps you could give me an idea. thanks in advance!!

Can you say more about how the logic works for id 1+2? It seems in either case, whether x1 goes to 1 at t3 or not at all, we should compare y1 between t2+t3. What if x1_t1 were 1, would that still look like id 3 where we compare t1 to t2? It seems that in the example case, t1 and t3 of x1 don't really matter, since it's just t2 that determines whether we compare t1+t2 or t2+t3.

Please run dput(head(df)) so it's easier for us to use your data

Why do different x_*-values result in the same selection principle? I.e. compare line 1 and 3 (id 1, 3).

1) dplyr Using dat shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, define the x1_* columns as x1 and then y1_* columns as y1 and the index of the match to the first 1 (or the last y1 if none) as i.  Then use i to extract the desired values from x1 and y1.
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(
    x1 = pick(starts_with("x1")), 
    y1 = pick(starts_with("y1")),
    i = match(1, x1, length(x1)), .by = id) %>%
  summarize(y1_before = y1[[i-1]], y1_after = y1[[i]], .by = id)

giving
  id y1_before y1_after
1  1       110      150
2  2       140      180
3  3        90      150

2) Base R Pretty much the same logic can be used in base R:
do.call("rbind", by(dat, dat$id, \(z) with(z, {
  x1 <- z[grep("x1", names(z))]
  y1 <- z[grep("y1", names(z))]
  i <- match(1, x1, length(x1))
  data.frame(id, y1_before = y1[[i-1]], y1_after = y1[[i]])
})))

Note
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  x1_t1 = integer(3),
  x1_t2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L),
  x1_t3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L),
  y1_t1 = c(100L, 150L, 90L),
  y1_t2 = c(110L, 140L, 150L),
  y1_t3 = c(150L, 180L, 160L)
)


This is long, and I'd like to see what shorter approaches people can come up with.
To do this in dplyr, I think it's simplest to reshape the data. I do this in two steps with tidyr::pivot_longer() and tidyr::pivot_wider(), but I think this could probably be done in once step with pivot_longer_spec().
Then I count how many x1==1's there have been in each id, removing any observations beyond the first x1==1. Then I take the last two remaining observations within each id.
Finally, pivot wider again with custom names.
library(tidyverse)  # includes dplyr and tidyr, each used below

df |>
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c("class", "time"), names_sep = "_") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = value) |>

  filter(cumsum(x1) <= 1, .by = id) |>
  slice_tail(n = 2, by = id) |>

  mutate(time = if_else(row_number() == 1, "before", "after"), .by = id) |>
  select(-x1) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, names_glue = "y1_{time}", values_from = y1)

Result
     id y1_before y1_after
  <int>     <int>    <int>
1     1       110      150
2     2       140      180
3     3        90      150


Source data:
read.table(text = "  id x1_t1 x1_t2 x1_t3 y1_t1 y1_t2 y1_t3
1  1     0     0     0   100   110   150
2  2     0     0     1   150   140   180
3  3     0     1     1    90   150   160") -> df


Never knew about using read.table like that! That will be helpful for SO posts

Solution using a mix of data.table and dplyr. data.table melt allows pivoting out into multiple columns, using the measure.vars parameter and measure function. I am a little confused by your desired output. id==1  never gets x1==1 so I'm not sure how that's valid. My method assumes that was a mistake.
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(
  id= c(1, 2, 3),
  x1_t1= c(0, 0, 0),
  x1_t2= c(0, 0, 1),
  x1_t3= c(0, 1, 1),
  y1_t1= c(100, 150, 90),
  y1_t2= c(110, 140, 150),
  y1_t3= c(150, 180, 160)
)

df |>
  melt(measure.vars = measure(value.name, t, sep="_")) |>
  dplyr::arrange(id, t) |>
  dplyr::mutate(x1_lead = data.table::shift(x1, n=1L, type = "lead"),
                x1_lag = data.table::shift(x1, n=1L, type = "lag")) |>
  dplyr::filter((x1==0 & x1_lead==1) | (x1==1 & x1_lag==0)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(before_after = 
                  fcase(x1==0 & x1_lead==1, "y1_before",
                        x1==1 & x1_lag==0, "y1_after")
                ) |>
  dplyr::select(id, before_after, y1) |>
  dcast(id ~ before_after, value.var = "y1") |>
  dplyr::select(id, y1_before, y1_after)

Key: <id>
      id y1_before y1_after
   <num>     <num>    <num>
1:     2       140      180
2:     3        90      150

